# Make the content of td table linkable

Tags: php, html, variables, html-table

Please can someone review this code and tell me how to get the content of `<td>` table clickable?

```
<?php
    include 'database.php';
    $pdo = Database::connect();
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY product_id DESC';
    foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'. $row['cat_id']        . '</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $row['brand_id']      . '</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $row['product_title'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $row['product_img1']  . '</td>'; 
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    Database::disconnect();
?>
```

What I want is to make by example `$row['brand_id']` a link that redirect to the brand details.

Comment: just use an anchor, create another page like `details.php`, echo it inside an `href` attribute, simplest would be like: `href="detail.php?id=<echo the brand id here>"`. from that details page just use that id into selecting that particular row that you selected, after that you're going to have to code it yourself

Comment: the prob i have is with this         echo '<td>'   .$row['brand_id'].  '</td>';  i kept trying to put it inside <a href....using many combinations...it kept returning error. dont know what syntax to use

Comment: its not a problem, you haven't even tried. just add the HTML anchor in your string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your TD has to have a hyperlink in it.

```
echo '<td><a href="URL?brand_id='. $row['brand_id']. '">'. $row['brand_id']. '</a></td>';
```

with `URL?brand_id=...` being the URL of the page with the brand details, where you pass your brand_id into.

Comment: Sergey Sergeyovich You are marvelous.thanks very much.